# Как обновить текущий фрагмент ViewPager из этого же фрагмента

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Есть `ViewPager` и в нем табы с `RecyclerView`. На элементе `RecyclerView` есть `icon` избранного, при нажатии на который он должен поменять свой вид. На данный момент получается, что при нажатии на этот элемент значение для него в базе меняется, а вот на экране все остается без изменений. Для `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` есть метод который обновляет содержимое `ViewPager` `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Но у меня не получается вызвать его из текущего фрагмента. Просьба помочь.

```
public class ViewPagerPhraseAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private  List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private  List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerPhraseAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // Возвращает фрагмент для отображения для этой страницы
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PhraseFragmentTabPager.newInstance(position, fragmentTitleList.get(position));
    }

    // Возвращает общее количество страниц
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    // Возвращает заголовок страницы для верхнего индикатора
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Если адаптер в активити, то сделайте там метод с вызовом обновления адаптера, а во фрагменте кастуйте getActivity() к типу вашей эктивити и вызывайте метод

Comment: в моем случае нужно было метод объявить, как статик